# Reading from a text file error

Tags: c#

So I've got a text file called "NEW.txt" and I want to read its contents from the console window. I realize that there is more than one way to skin a cat, but I was trying to implement this one

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("NEW.txt"))
{
    String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

But I get the error that 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter."

What is the TextWriter and why is it closed?

Update:

```
       //using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("NEW.txt"))
       //     {
       //         System.Console.SetOut(writer);
       //         System.Console.WriteLine("Hello text file");
       //         System.Console.WriteLine("I'm writing to you from visual C#");
       //     }

       //This following part only works when the previous block is commented it out

        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("NEW.txt"))
        {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(content);

        }
```

Assuming the problem was the this line "System.Console.SetOut(writer);" How can I change the output stream back to the console window ?

Comment: Where are you calling that code from?

Comment: @AndrewBarber umm, Main method.

Comment: What kind of project? Oh, and here's a hint: There's only one operation in that code that involves *writing* to a stream. The `TextWriter` is encapsulated within that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber A regular Console Application. That one operation is Consolle.WriteLine(content) isn't it?. If it is, I do not understand what you mean by encapsulated within that ?

Comment: There's a `TextWriter` being created there, but not directly by you. Just like your code creates a `FileStream`, but you don't see it directly. Do you have any other code that's running on different threads doing anything? I just compiled this exact code and ran it fine.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't know the first thing about threads, but this gave me the idea that it might my earlier code of writing to the text file using the same format as the one in my question but with StreamWriter and changing the Console.SetOut(writer) (writer is a StreamWriter object). It seems that indeed this block of code was the problem. It works fine now.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I assume the problem was that I changed the stream I'm writing to the writer object. Ok, so how can I change the writing stream back to console window

Comment: It wouldn't be something so straightforward... Have you created a new Console project with *only* that code, and nothing else? What else is your code doing? Threads? Forms?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Nope, nothing sophisticated at all. I commented everything out and it the code I've posted works fine only when I comment out the using StreamWriter block. I've updated my question to show the full code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Alright. I'll just add it to the list of the unreasonable things on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Mustafa: click that link and see the discussion around it. This isn't a Usenet newsgroup.

Comment: Also, @JohnSaunders is absolutely right here. The tag `C#` is all that was needed. Putting it in the title too actually has some negative consequences, and is just extra noise. Your question would already be prefixed with the top-used tag (C#, in this case) in many question lists, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your code. You noted that it only works when you comment out the top at the part:

```
   //using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("NEW.txt"))
   //     {
   //         System.Console.SetOut(writer);
   //         System.Console.WriteLine("Hello text file");
   //         System.Console.WriteLine("I'm writing to you from visual C#");
   //     }

   //This following part only works when the previous block is commented it out

    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("NEW.txt"))
    {
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(content);

    }
```

Now that you've included the code you were commenting out, I see the problem here... You are setting a `StreamWriter` as the 'Out' for console. And then you are closing that `StreamWriter` - closing the associated `TextWriter`. And then you are trying to use it again later, causing the error: The `TextWriter` has been closed because you closed it by that code.

To fix this, change your commented code to do this:

```
   using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("NEW.txt"))
        {
            /* This next line is the root of your problem */
            //System.Console.SetOut(writer);

            /* Just write directly with `writer` */
            writer.WriteLine("Hello text file");
            writer.WriteLine("I'm writing to you from visual C#");
        }
```

There's no need to go through `Console` here. Just write with the writer directly.